# Trying to conditionally append tuples from a list of tuples to sublists of tuples in a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I am at a loss on how to achieve what I want, so I'm posting here.

I have a dictionary where each value is a list of tuples (I'll call it `dict1`), which I am cross referencing against a list of tuples (I'll call it `list1`).  The idea is to append any tuple that is in list1 to each sublist in `dict1` if it doesn't already exist in the sublist in the form of (tuple, 0).

Here's what it looks like:

```
dict1 = {2011: [('Debt collection', 5572),
                ('Mortgage', 4483),
                ('Student loan', 431)],
         2012: [('Consumer Loan', 480),
                ('Student loan', 1632),
                ('Medical loan', 1632),
                ('Prepaid card', 83)]}

list1 = [('Debt collection', 5572),
         ('Mortgage', 4483),
         ('Credit reporting', 3230),
         ('Checking or savings account', 2068),
         ('Student loan', 1632),
         ('Credit card or prepaid card', 1577),
         ('Bank account or service', 1327),
         ('Credit card', 1156),
         ('Consumer Loan', 480)]
```

I want my code to check if the first part of each tuple in list1 exists in each value list of dict1, and if it doesn't, to append it to each value list in the form of (tuple, 0):

```
dict1 = {2011: [('Debt collection', 5572),
                ('Mortgage', 4483),
                ('Student loan', 431),
                ('Credit reporting', 0),
                ('Checking or savings account', 0),
                ('Credit card or prepaid card', 0),
                ('Bank account or service', 0),
                ('Credit card', 0),
                ('Consumer Loan', 0)],
         2012: [('Consumer Loan', 480),
                ('Student loan', 1632),
                ('Medical loan', 1632),
                ('Prepaid card', 83),
                ('Debt collection', 0),
                ('Mortgage', 0),
                ('Credit reporting', 0),
                ('Checking or savings account', 0),
                ('Credit card or prepaid card', 0),
                ('Bank account or service', 0),
                ('Credit card', 0)]}
```

I've tried first to extract the first part of each tuple in list1 as a separate list:

```
 available = [tpl[0] for tpl in list1]
```

Then I attempt the following:

```
 dict1.update(v.extend(tuple((tpl[0],0)) for tpl in v \ 
              for k, v in dict1.items() \
              if tpl[0] not in available))
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-79-53b4b903b6f4> in <module>()
----> 1 dict1.update(v.extend(list(tuple((tpl[0],0)) for tpl in v for k, v in dict1.items()                      
if tpl[0] not in available)))

<ipython-input-79-53b4b903b6f4> in <genexpr>(.0)
----> 1 dict1.update(v.extend(list(tuple((tpl[0],0)) for tpl in v for k, v in dict1.items()                      
if tpl[0] not in available)))

TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable
```

I was looking but didn't find anything that really went over a similar type of case.  I'm assuming that I have to use .update for dict1 and also .extend on each list of values (v) in order to deal with each list individually.

Comment: Note that generator expressions return a generator, not a list, and generators can't be subscripted; as the error notes. You could either use a list comprehension instead of a generator expression, or use `list` to force the generator into a list.

Comment: I'm not great with generator expressions, so I'm trying to understand my code a bit better...is the generator expression here the one that begins with v.extend?

Comment: Yes. The part that looks like a list comprehension but uses `()` instead of square braces. I can't see in there where you're subscripting the generator, but that's the only instance of a generator that I see.

Comment: Hmm...I've tried putting square brackets before v.extend and after "available)" but I'm still getting the same error message ('generator' object is not subscriptable)

Comment: Python isn't my main language, and I'm quite tired, so I may be missing something. Hopefully someone more fluent will be able to help you.

Comment: It looks like you're *really* wanting a `collections.OrderedDict`, not a list of tuples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert each value into a `dict` temporarily, use `get` to ensure a full complement of values, and write it back as a list. This requires no imports:

```
for k in dict1:
    d = dict(dict1[k])
    dict1[k] = [(item, d.get(item, 0)) for item, _ in list1]
```

If you want to have a dictionary in the output, the last line barely changes:

```
dict1[k] = {item: d.get(item, 0)) for item, _ in list1}
```

Or, if order matters and you are using Python < 3.6:

```
dict1 = OrderedDict(item, d.get(item, 0)) for item, _ in list1)
```

While I would encourage you not to, a one liner is possible:

```
dict1 = {k: [(item, d.get(item, 0)) for item, _ in list1] for k, d in ((k, dict(v)) for k, v in dict1.items())}
```

Answer (score 1):

For your problem, dictionaries are easier to handle than lists of tuples. In this case, you can combine mappings via a dictionary comprehension.

```
from operator import itemgetter

# create dictionary with all keys set to 0
allkeys = dict.fromkeys(map(itemgetter(0), list1), 0)

# for each year, combine dictionary mappings
dict1 = {k: {**allkeys, **dict(v)} for k, v in dict1.items()}
```

You can, if you wish, convert back to lists of tuples:

```
res = {k: list(v.items()) for k, v in dict1.items()}
```

Result for the nested dictionary option:

```
{2011: {'Debt collection': 5572,
  'Mortgage': 4483,
  'Credit reporting': 0,
  'Checking or savings account': 0,
  'Student loan': 431,
  'Credit card or prepaid card': 0,
  'Bank account or service': 0,
  'Credit card': 0,
  'Consumer Loan': 0},
 2012: {'Debt collection': 0,
  'Mortgage': 0,
  'Credit reporting': 0,
  'Checking or savings account': 0,
  'Student loan': 1632,
  'Credit card or prepaid card': 0,
  'Bank account or service': 0,
  'Credit card': 0,
  'Consumer Loan': 480,
  'Medical loan': 1632,
  'Prepaid card': 83}}
```